# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Если услышу, что кто-то грубо выражается(,) - будет отвечать за свои слова.

Нужна ли запятая перед тире?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вы по насущной надобности, то ставьте. Объяснить её постановку всегда проще, чем отсутствие.

А если "за порассуждать"... 
Я в этом вопросе уже несколько лет пытаюсь найти концы, т.е. исчерпывающее правило, - безуспешно. Самое осмысленное, что удалось услышать, это то, что запятая и тире, требуемые по разным мотивам, не поглощаются друг другом. Так ли оно на самом деле - не знаю, ибо приводил контрпримеры, на которые не получил разумных объяснений. Тем не менее в данном случае готов воспользоваться этим советом - и рекомендовать сохранить запятую. Запятая требуется чтобы закрыть придаточное "что кто-то грубо выражается", тире - для обозначения причинно-следственной связи в бессоюзном сложносочиненном.
Да и не смотрится оно без запятой, если честно. Можно воспринять как "если услышу, что кто-то.... будет отвечать за свои слова".

Answer (score 1):

Я бы добавил в главное предложение местоимение "он": "он будет отвечать за свои слова". Запятая закрывает второе придаточное предложение, поэтому обязательно нужна.

Comment: Нужно ли тире после запятой?..
Если (я) услышу, что кто-то грубо выражается, (то я) потребую ответить за такие слова.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не нужна. Насколько мне известно, запятая перед тире ставиться только при оформлении прямой речи, а обороты и придаточные предложения могут быть выделены запятой с одной стороны и тире с другой.